# Read column from excel and list greatest to lowest?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

SO I'm able to read from an Excel file and get the value of the cell I want. What if I want to read from 1 whole column (with row 1 as the title) and list the values from greatest to least?

```
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Test\Test.xlsx"

        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)

        Dim DS = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DS)
        Dim Dt = DS.Tables(0).Rows(10)(1)

        'dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)


        MsgBox(Dt)


        MyConnection.Close()
```

My Excel file is something like:

```
ROW 1: NAME | AGE
ROW 2: Admin| 15
ROW 3: User | 16
```

That code above only gets a single cell value, I'd like to get all the Age value and sort it from highest (16) to lowest (15) and what the name is?

Comment: What is your interpretation of `Dim Dt = DS.Tables(0).Rows(10)(1)` ? What does the 10 and 1 following rows mean?

Comment: You could try an Order By clause in your Select statement but first tell OleDb that the first row are column names.

Comment: @Mary the .Rows(10)(1) means row 1 in column 1

Comment: Index 10 would be row 11 and column index 1 would be the second column. These are zero based collections. I thought there might be some confusion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim path As String = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Test\Test.xlsx"

MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$] order by age desc", MyConnection)

Dim DS = New System.Data.DataSet
MyCommand.Fill(DS)

For Each r As DataRow In DS.Tables(0).Rows
    MsgBox(String.Format("{0}:{1}", r.Item("name"), r.Item("age")))
Next

MyConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. Can't believe it seems so hard at first...thank you. I'm new to using the OleDb, so I'm not sure what its capable of. Would it be possible to only select a certain range? for example Column ("age) from 2 to 10 ? I should rephrase this, at the bottom of my sheet, there is a row that adds up how many people total. Obviously, this row will have the highest number, so it will always show up first.

I was thinking it should be something like "select * from [Sheet1$2:10] order by age desc" ?

Comment: Not sure why I can't edit my comment. Meant to type something like this : 
select * from [Sheet1$C2:C10] order by age desc

Comment: If you want to a summary of age column, then SQL is

 select sum(age) as age from [Sheet1$] 

Since this case is "SQL" rather than "OLEDB", I suggest you also study about SQL.